# How to change camera Exposure on ios

Tags: ios, swift

I create AVCaptureSession

```
captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
    videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.frame
    videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

    guard let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else {
            print("Unable to access back camera!")
            return
    }
    self.chaprerDevice = backCamera
    changeExpousureMode(mode:.autoExpose)

    do {
     cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
     stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
      if captureSession.canAddInput(cameraInput) &&     captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
        captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
        captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        setupLivePreview()
        }
        } catch let error  {
            print("Error Unable to initialize back camera:  \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

and i implement exposure method on slider

```
   @IBAction func didChangeExpousureValue(_ sender: UISlider) {
    print(sender.value)
    do {
        try self.chaprerDevice!.lockForConfiguration()
        //self.chaprerDevice!.setExposureModeCustom(duration: AVCaptureDevice.currentExposureDuration, iso: sender.value, completionHandler: nil)
        self.chaprerDevice.setExposureTargetBias(sender.value, completionHandler: nil)
            self.chaprerDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch let error {
              NSLog("Could not lock device for configuration: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I want that when the slider value changes to add or subtract that value to the current exposure.

Another problem I have is that I sometimes change the brightness on the camera and then exit that controller and enter another controller that uses the camera but the exposure is not touched on that controller and the screen is completely white

Comment: Please don't ask multi questions in one topic.

Comment: @koen i can find